# Get specific value from string using split fucntion

Tags: java, string

I have String something like this

```
APIKey testapikey=mysecretkey
```

I want to get mysecretkey to  String attribute

What i tried is below

```
String[] couple = string.split(" ");
String[]   values=couple[1].split("=");
String mykey= values[1];
```

Is this right way?

Comment: Why not `string.split("=")[1]` ?

Comment: `mykey = string.substring( string.indexOf("=")+1 );` doesn't create an array.

Comment: For data in "key=value" format the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `String.replaceAll(...)` method.

```
String string = "APIKey testapikey=mysecretkey";
// [.*key=] - match the substring ending with "key="
// [(.*)] - match everything after the "key=" and group the matched characters
// [$1] - replace the matched string by the value of cpaturing group number 1
string = string.replaceAll(".*key=(.*)", "$1");
System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `split()` you will be *unnecessarily* creating an array of Strings.

Use String `myString = originalString.replaceAll(".*=","");`

Answer (score 0):

I think using split here is pretty error prone. A small change in the format of the incoming string (such as a space being added) could result in a bug that's hard to diagnose. My recommendation would be to play it safe and use a regular expression to ensure the text is exactly as you expect:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("APIKey testapikey=(\\w*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(apiKeyText);
if (!matcher.matches())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("apiKey does not match pattern");
String apiKey = matcher.group();
```

That code documents your intentions much better than use of split and picks up unexpected changes in format. The only possible downside is performance but assuming you make `pattern` a `static final` (to ensure it's compiled once) then unless you are calling this millions of times then I very much doubt it will be an issue.